# Post with curl, postman works but java gives SSL error

Tags: java, rest, ssl, curl

I make a basic post request to get a token in Java and I always get SSL certificate Handshake error :

```
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String encoding = "YXBwLmJidmEuS3JlZGlsdafasdfasdf0bzpUeHZUUDJLVEdiKkhmbGNJeHNUDQ1d2tEU1dGak9TUk1zSVN3d2owYzJlJE9adU5rVmVZ";
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://connect.bbva.com/token?grant_type=client_credentials");
        httppost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

I have tried doing the same with Advanced Rest Client and a shell command and it works like a charm:

```
curl -X POST -i  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Basic YXBwLmJidmEuS3JlZGl0bzpUeHZUUDJLVEdiKkhmbGNJeHNUNHU2RDE3MkFFa2R2QDQ1d2tEU1dGak9TUk1zSVN3d2owYzJlJE9adU5rVmVZ" https://connect.bbva.com/token?grant_type=client_credentials
```

I have also checked curl with the correct truststore option, which my default java takes to check if there is no problem with truststore and there aint one:

```
-cacerts=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

Now I have used in Java `java.net.URLConnection` library too to test but it does not work.

I have also tested it with the content type but to no avail:

```
("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
```

I have also tested this on java7 and java8, oracle both.

I have tried everything, I as a basic, mediocre java developer could have.

Btw, incase it helps, my curl response comes with the following headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 18 May 2017 09:29:11 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 751
```

I also checked the ssl-debug-logs using:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");
```

and it uses the correct truststore.

Comment: You should check what the [SSL debug logs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) say

Comment: what exactly am i supposed to check from there. The keystore and truststore. Thats I have checked.

Comment: Well it depends on what the logs say. You should see the different certificates of the truststore loaded (you may use an other store than the one you think) and have an explicit message telling you the certificate isn't trusted if that's the problem.

Comment: @Aaron, I see a lot of certificates, when I run this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this error just by changing the Java version from `java-oracle8` to `java-openjdk8`.